# How to draw an arc with rounded edges in Android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

I tried to implement a simple pie chart and was faced with the following problem - I need to make the edges of the sector rounded as it's shown in the image

[image]

Searched for some examples, found that it's possible to achieve by setting a cap. But as I can see, it's possible to set the cap only for stroke style, while I use the fill. can someone help me to solve the problem? here's the way how my view looks like:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
@Composable
fun PieChart(modifier: Modifier, progress: Double) {
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.then(modifier)) {
        drawCircle(
            color = Color.White,
            radius = 130F,
            center = Offset(150F, 150F)
        )
        drawArc(
            brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(SecondaryGradient),
            startAngle = -90F,
            sweepAngle = (360 * progress / 100).toFloat(),
            useCenter = true,
            size = Size(300F, 300F),
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Compose is built around Android, and in the case of Canvas is limited to the same API, just wrapped by Compose. In such cases, I look for Android solutions - you can always use a native canvas with `drawIntoCanvas { it.nativeCanvas ... }` or find the corresponding API in Compose.